# Masking textfield for password in Maya UI using Python

Tags: python, maya

I have created a UI in Maya to send some information for rendering in a mail. For that the user has to type different data including username and password. But when typing the password, it is visible like the other texts. Is there a way where the password could appear like dots or asterisks?? The script is written in Python. Below is the image of the UI.

[image]

Comment: I think maya ui downt provide such field, you should move to pyqt.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Yeah I do use QT as well but in this case, the text field for number of layers is variable ie.. if the user adds more layers then the text fields increase accordingly which could get a bit complicated with QT.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the changeCommand of the text field to a function that would save the text to a variable and replace the text shown with an asterisk for each character.

```
import pymel.core as pm

class myWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.password = ''
        win = pm.window(title='Test')
        lo = pm.columnLayout()
        self.pswdField = pm.textField(changeCommand=self.hideText)
        win.show()

    def hideText(self, *args):
        self.password = self.pswdField.getText()
        self.pswdField.setText("*" * len(self.pswdField.getText()))
```

That's just one way and it's not very robust..but I would definitely look into Qt like Daniel pointed out.

Comment: I tried this but I wanted the password to not show even while typing.I am doing this part in QT and the rest in Maya itself. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For my code, I tried something like this:

```
self.Passwd.keyPressEvent = lambda event : self.encryption()

def encryption(self):
        self.a = "*"
        self.Passwd.setText(self.Passwd.text() + self.a)
```

This is just for encoding the characters with * as you type.
You still need to capture the input into a variable or something.

And somehow segregate the keys that are not allowed in the password.

hope it gives a start.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below function best suited for the above problem:

```
    self.Passwd = QLineEdit("Password")
    self.Passwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Qt is too much trouble and you don't need it 100% reliable this might suffice. It's similar to the answer from Argiri, but it replaces text as it is typed, and appends each keypress to a variable.

```
import pymel.core as pm

class LoginWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.password = ""
        self.win = pm.window()
        lo = pm.columnLayout()
        self.userField = pm.textField()
        self.passField = pm.textField(textChangedCommand=self.obscure)
        self.goButton = pm.button("Login", c=self.go)
        self.win.show()

    def obscure(self, *args):
        new_pw = self.passField.getText()
        if len(new_pw) > len(self.password):
            self.password+=new_pw[-1]
        elif len(new_pw) < len(self.password):
            self.password = self.password[0:-1]
        self.passField.setText(u"\u2022" * len(self.password))
        
    def go(self, *args):
        print ("u: {} p: {}".format(self.userField.getText(), self.password))
        pm.deleteUI(self.win)
        
                
lw = LoginWindow()
```

Note that if the user tried to edit the middle of the password, or tried to type it in the wrong order the reported password would be mangled. I'm not sure if that's a problem in the real world.